# Method incorrectly being run twice

Tags: c#

Why, when I am running this code, does the question from the 2nd method repeat?

```
using System;

namespace mdisafmidf
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello world!");
            CallMethod0();
            Console.WriteLine(CallMethod0());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        public static string CallMethod0()
        {
            string x;
            Console.WriteLine("Do you agree this is a good day?");
            Console.WriteLine("a)Yes   b)No");
            x = Console.ReadLine();
            if (x == "Yes")
            {
                return ("Of course this is a good day");
            }
            else
            {
                return ("Oh, try and stay more positive!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it can be trivially debugged with a debugger or print statements and has no value to other users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `CallMethod0`, it returns a string.  You need to store the result to a string variable, and then Console.Write the variable.  Since you have the method call in there twice, it is running twice.

In other words, change it to:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello world!");
    string result = CallMethod0(); // store the result like this
    Console.WriteLine(result); // print the result - don't call the method again
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: No worries, it's not a waste.

Comment: Sorry, I am really new to this community, and I am just trying to get around.

Comment: @Alex we were all knew to SO at one point.  Welcome to SO.  A word of friendly advice: just be patient, and try not to take downvotes too personally.

Answer (score 7):

You're calling the method twice, so it's running twice.

```
CallMethod0();
Console.WriteLine(CallMethod0());
```

Answer (score 0):

Just modify your code to be like this:

```
var message = CallMethod0();
Console.WriteLine(message);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `CallMethod0()` twice.
Above you have `CallMethod0();` and `Console.WriteLine(callMethod0());`
If you remove `CallMethod0();` it works fine.